# Import Dockerfile from different local directory via FROM

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-multi-stage-build

I want to create a multistage build process whereas each of the docker files are nested inside their own directories locally with their corresponding dependencies that are ADDed in for each Docker file. Is there a way to import a Docker file from a different directory locally whereas I am able to import it with Docker's `FROM` command, to create several stages in a build?

If not, would I be able to `ADD` the other staged Docker file's into the current Docker file and then use `FROM` inside the docker container, deleting it after it is added and used in `FROM`?

Maybe I am thinking about multistage builds the wrong way.

Or can I simply run `FROM {path/to/docker/locally}`? This is not working for me.

Comment: Good point, it could be interesting to be able to make an "IMPORT https://github/com/user/repo/Dockerfile" in a Dockerfile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Is there a way to import a Docker file from a different directory locally whereas I am able to import it with Docker's FROM command, to create several stages in a build?

No. The `FROM` instruction is used to import pre-built images only, it can not be used to import a Dockerfile.

> If not, would I be able to ADD the other staged Docker file's into the current Docker file?

No. The `ADD` instruction can only copy files **inside the build context (which usually is the current working directory)** to containers. You cannot `ADD ../something /something`.

> Or can I simply run FROM {path/to/docker/locally}?

No. But one way that is gonna work for you is, to build the other image first, say its name is `first-image:latest`, then you can use the `COPY` instruction to copy files from that image:

```
COPY --from=first-image:latest /some/file /some/file
```

Comment: Update: The `FROM` command [has been expanded](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/multistage-build/#use-a-previous-stage-as-a-new-stage) to be able to reference another ephemeral image built during a prior stage of the build (which is similar, but not exactly what the OP asked). This could be used in conjunction with some bash scripting using the `cat` tool to achieve the OP's desired result.

Answer (score 8):

The best solution i have found to this so far is to use **Dockerfile stages**

#### Put all this in a single `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM php:8.1-fpm AS base

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    libzip-dev libonig-dev \
    libwebp-dev # ...

RUN docker-php-ext-install zip mbstring pdo pdo_mysql gd bcmath sockets opcache soap gmp intl

# Worker
FROM base AS worker
RUN apt install -y supervisor 

# CLI
FROM base AS cli
RUN apt-get install -yq git unzip
RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
```

#### And then you can use it in `docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
services:
  worker:
    build:
      context: php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: worker

  cli:
    build:
      context: php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: cli
```

This will make the containers build efficiently and the `base` will be built only once.
You can also use the `base` itself as a target.

Answer (score 7):

If you use Docker 20.10+, you can do this:

```
# syntax = edrevo/dockerfile-plus

INCLUDE+ {path/to/docker/locally}

RUN ...
```

The `INCLUDE+` instruction gets imported by the first line in the Dockerfile. You can read more about the dockerfile-plus at https://github.com/edrevo/dockerfile-plus

Comment: Looks like `dockerfile-plus` is no longer maintained (last commit was 2+ years ago). Is there a maintained solution that achieves the same?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, what you are trying to achieve is to build an image and then use the same image and build something (the next »stage«) on top of it.

Docker supports this concept, but not by importing another Dockerfile.

Dockerfiles and the directory they are in are meant to be self-contained, i. e. the only things you need to build the image are these directory contents. Therefore, you cannot load other Dockerfiles from other directories.

The way to go would be to build a base image, e. g. `myappimage`, using a Dockerfile `myappimage/Dockerfile`. After you have built it, you can refer to this base image in another Dockerfile (e. g. `mytestingimage/Dockerfile`) using `FROM myappimage` to build an image (`mytestingimage`) on top of `myappimage`.

Then, `mytestingimage` is exactly like `myappimage` but with additional layers added by your `ADD` and other commands.